# After creating local resource file page is not showing anything

Tags: asp.net

I have a website that is multi-lingual and I have now several pages that work good with the local resource files.
One page doesn't want to show anything.

I have first created the page and when I had it finished I created the local resource file.
The I copied it twice and renamed those to the represent the two languages.

I have not changed anything inside the resource files nor the webpage itself.
When I run the website and go to that page, it shows the stuff from the masterpage, but nothing else.

Withing the masterpages contentplaceholder I have an updatepanel and Updateprogress. All controls are within the update panel.

I have also tried it without the updatepanel, not change, still nothing to see.

I have removed all the meta-tags from my page and deleted the resource files and then the pages shows as it should.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Can you show the code where the resource files are being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured that one out....

Apparently if you have an ASP table on your page it gets meta-tagged for the resource file as well.
I removed the meta-tags from the rows and cells and my page appeared.

Strange behaviour, but now we know it.... :-)